# object reference is required, also dump object into messagebox tips

Tags: c#

i'm getting an error with this code `new RoutedEventHandler(Notifications.showNotifications(window));` saying:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Notifications.showNotifications(Window)'

Also, can I get an example of how I could dump out each Dictionary object from within my `_notifications` object in the `runtimeObject` class? I need to do this when `showNotifications` is called!

When I say dump out, based on the test notifications which I try to add in the code, I just want to display a MessageBox to show that they are being added, so using the code above the MessageBox would show:

**MessageBox**

```
Error Code: 1, Text: Error 1
Error Code: 2, Text: Normal Message
Error Code: 3, Text: Tip
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Test_Project
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            //Startup
            Window main = new MainWindow();
            main.Show();

            //Attach Event Handlers to MainWindow
            if (!attachEventHandlers(main))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fatal Error: Unable to attach event handlers, contact administrator!", 
                    "Fatal Error!",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            }
        }
        public bool attachEventHandlers(Window window)
        {

            //window.MouseMove += new RoutedEventHandler(Notifications.showNotifications(window));
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Notifications
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Show the notifications
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="window"></param>
        public void showNotifications(Window window)
        {
            // Find the resource, then cast it to a runtimeObject
            var runtime = (runtimeObject)Application.Current.TryFindResource("runtimeVariables");

            //Create messagebox with all the notifications in to test
        }

        public bool addNotifications()
        {
            // Find the resource, then cast it to a runtimeObject
            var runtime = (runtimeObject)Application.Current.TryFindResource("runtimeVariables");

            //Create Dictionary
            Dictionary<int, string> arr = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            arr.Add(1, "Error 1");
            arr.Add(2, "Normal Message");
            arr.Add(3, "Tip");

            //Create test notifications
            runtime.notifications.Add(arr);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Global values for use during application runtime
    /// </summary>
    public class runtimeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

        }

        //Can the application be closed?
        private bool _inProgress = false;
        public bool inProgress
        {
            get { return _inProgress; }
            set
            {
                if (_inProgress != value)
                {
                    _inProgress = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("inProgress");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifications held
        /// Array((int)type,(string)"message")
        /// </summary>
        private List<Dictionary<int, string>> _notifications;
        public List<Dictionary<int, string>> notifications
        {
            get { return _notifications; }
            set
            {
                if (_notifications != value)
                {
                    _notifications = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("notifications");
                }
            }
        }

        //Selected folder to search in
        private int _uploadProgress = 0;
        public int uploadProgress
        {
            get { return _uploadProgress; }
            set
            {
                if (_uploadProgress != value)
                {
                    //int Angle = (_uploadProgress * 360) / 100;
                    //Classes.CircularProgress.RenderArc(Angle);
                    _uploadProgress = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("uploadProgress");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "new ..." statement is creating an object, but I don't see it being assigned to a variable, e.g. a reference. This may be the issue.

Comment: What does "dump out" mean?

Comment: See edit for what I mean by dump out